# How to convert this HTML to Outlook?

Tags: html, css, outlook

MS-Outlook 2021 is not accepting the reserved words `position`, `transform`, `left`, `top`, etc..., but the format I hope it sends is like this: The div container needs to overlap the half of the image vertically. I know outlook doesn't accept some keywords, but could anyone help with this challenge?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    style="width:100%;font-family:lato,\'helvetica neue\',helvetica,arial,sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
    <title>Login V1</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: darkgray;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        
        .container{
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50px;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            width: 700px;
            height: 700px;
            background-color: red;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        .bottom{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 160px;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: black;
        }
        
        .img-topo{
            max-width: 120%;
        }
        
        .img-bottom{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -195px;
        }
        
        
        .img-left{
            position: absolute;
            left: 120;
            max-width: 50%
        }
        
         .img-rigth{
            position: absolute;
            left: 400px;
            top: 35px;
        }
        
    </style>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>

<body>
    
    <img class="img-topo" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AITFw-zviIrecDSk828D53IFiyydVKCO59Xwd74Zn5W5ue3Y8T_-Fy4oNvh2gNZYBx5RuM3CwgdgGK8dBEn75wTnC-JKTAgS9Q=w2560-h1323">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
             <img class="img-left" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AITFw-wxJ-V2M4yuM9cPuUJiVvgiT58R--lKaJT5oBKg8KMjpawjneUBdzwYHHvnkSXxldQ77s5lR8bNcihcWYX4aEnOpc1tOA=w1920-h963">
            <img class="img-rigth" width="35%"
                                src="https://www.novaagri.com.br/image/png/logo_oficial.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <img class="img-bottom" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AITFw-xhGEU8c3mR1_TiG49L8aijixdonmGw0oEXxiqzsypDEIQG_Y3z19y4q0oWDcj6VLfiTUnXsqhEUmtgvnc1dY7nhCXPDw=w1920-h963">
        </div>
    </div>

    
</body>

</html>
```

This was the maximum I could achieve by viewing the outlook

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    style="width:100%;font-family:lato,\'helvetica neue\',helvetica,arial,sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
    <title>Login V1</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        
        .table-principal{
            width: 100%;
}
        
        .table-principal tr{
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        
        .white{
            background-color: white;
        }
        
    </style>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>

<body>    
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table-principal">
        <th colspan="3" style="position: fixed"><img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" width="100%" height="100" class="img-topo" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AITFw-zviIrecDSk828D53IFiyydVKCO59Xwd74Zn5W5ue3Y8T_-Fy4oNvh2gNZYBx5RuM3CwgdgGK8dBEn75wTnC-JKTAgS9Q=w2560-h1323"></th>
        
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: red" rowspan="5"><img width="100%" height="150px" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" class="img-topo" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AITFw-zviIrecDSk828D53IFiyydVKCO59Xwd74Zn5W5ue3Y8T_-Fy4oNvh2gNZYBx5RuM3CwgdgGK8dBEn75wTnC-JKTAgS9Q=w2560-h1323"></td>
                <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                <td style="background-color: red" rowspan="5"><img width="100%" height="150px" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" class="img-topo" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AITFw-zviIrecDSk828D53IFiyydVKCO59Xwd74Zn5W5ue3Y8T_-Fy4oNvh2gNZYBx5RuM3CwgdgGK8dBEn75wTnC-JKTAgS9Q=w2560-h1323"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: white; width: 400px; display: block"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                    <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                    <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                    <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                    <td >&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: white">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: black">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: black">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: black">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: black">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: black">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="background-color: black">12</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```